# Java Generics Curiosity

Tags: java, generics, collections, bounded-wildcard

I have an interface `A`, which class `B` implements.

The following generic method works

```
public static <T, U extends T> List<T> listFactory(Collection<U> source) {
    return new ArrayList<T>(source);
}
```

but

```
public static <T> List<T> listFactory(Collection<? extends T> source) {
    return new ArrayList<T>(source);
}
```

does not (compilation error, type mismatch), when I am directing the output into

```
List<A> tester = listFactory(B.defaultCollectionFactory(3));
```

`defaultCollectionFactory(int count)` statically provides a collection of `B`s, with a default labeling scheme.

Any insights as to why that is?  It seems like the generic U and wildcard are doing the same thing.

Comment: how does it "not work"? what is the error message?

Comment: Looks like you have two right answers below for what's causing the problem - but I wouldn't take their advice literally. Stick with the non-wildcard version, so that the caller of the method doesn't have to work around this limitation of wildcards.

Comment: @newacct: compilation error, type mismatch

Comment: @Carl: i tested this on my mac os x 10.5 w/ java 5 and the error was "incompatible types required: java.util.List<test.A> found: java.util.List<test.B>"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first construct, you are specifying that you are returning a `List` of the interface of the item that was passed in.  You specify the relationship between the passed in Object and the return Object type in the  `U extends T` direction.  In this case, the compiler can associate `A` and `B` with `T` and`U` respectively.

In the second, there is no such differentiation, so the compiler assumes that `T` refers to `B` and will type the return value as `List<B>`.  You then fall into the trap where, although `B` is an instance of `A`, `List<B>` is not an instance of `List<A>`.   The compiler will complain:

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<B> to List<A>

You will find that, with the first construct, you have the liberty of specifying a `List` of any interface the `B` implements or any superclass in the `B` hierarchy (`List<Object>`, for example), and the compiler will not complain.

Comment: So the precedence (sort of) for type inference is from arguments first, then return type for these sort of generics.

Comment: chosen based on good explanation (which erickson also offers), plus avoiding advising the Class.<T> structure, which I think is ugly.

Answer (score 4):

The compiler is inferring a different type parameter for the `listFactory` method than you expect. It infers that `T` is type `B`, so the signature is effectively `List<B> listFactory(Collection<? extends B> source)`. Specify the type parameter `A` by being explicit in the method invocation:

```
List<A> tester = Test.<A> listFactory(B.defaultCollectionFactory(3));
```

Comment: @erikson: This static call on a parameterized type actually works, doesn't make sense to me, can you break it down with an example and theory explanation, thanks.

Comment: Any static method can (really, should) be qualified by the class to which it belongs. The OP didn't specify what it is; I used "Test". So that would give you a normal static method call: `Test.listFactory(...)`. Then, the type arguments for any parameterized method can be specified explicitly, by adding them before the method name. That's the `<A>`. Put them together, and you get my answer.